# searching a pool of database with hours as integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a pool of signup database containing attributes like email, ip, created_at, etc, and I want to be a about to search dynamically based on how many hours in Time.now, e.g. search signup record 2 hours ago, without hardcoding those hours, but my solution is not working and sick. How can I achieve this? Below is the mess I have done:

**traffics_controller.rb**

```
class TrafficsController < BaseController
  def show
    @search_term = params[:search_term]
    @traffic =
        if params[:search_term] == 'time_calculated'
          SignupHistory.time_calculated
        else
          SignupHistory.all 
        end
  end
end
```

**model**

```
class SignupHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.time_calculated
    where('created_at > ?', Time.now - "#{time_difference}".hour)
  end
end
```

**show.html.slim**

```
# search form rows
.row
  .panel.panel-primary
    .panel-heading
      span = t('.search')
    .panel-body
      = form_tag admin_statistic_traffics_path, method: :get
        .col-xs-4 = text_field_tag :search_term, @search_term
        .col-xs-12.col-xs-offset-1 = submit_tag 'Search'
# Table rows
.row
  .panel.panel-primary
    .panel-heading
      span = t('admin_header.traffics')
    .panel-body
      = table_for(@traffic, class: 'table table-condensed table-hover') do |t|
        - t.column :id, 'S/N', class: 'col-xs-1'
        - t.column :email, 'Email', class: 'col-xs-2'
        - t.column :created_at, 'Signed in Date', class: 'col-xs-3' do |x|
          = x.created_at.strftime('%B %e, %Y at %I:%M %p')
        - t.column :login_location, 'Login Location', class: 'col-xs-3'
```

I want to be able to put 1 in the search field and search to pull out records in the table that got created 1 hour ago using `created_at` field. But its not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your search field? `time_calculated`? So you want to put `1` into the field instead of the string `time_calculated`? Or both - like `time_calculated 1`?

Comment: I just want to be dynamic to allow typing in an integer and search based on it.

Comment: @spickermann The only filed on the database into consideration is `created_at`. Its the only datetime field recording when the record is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution could be not using the string `time_calculated` as a trigger to only return recent `SignupHistory` records, but actually the existence of a number in that field.

```
# in your controller
def show
  @search_term = params[:search_term]
  @traffic =
      if params[:search_term].to_i > 0
        SignupHistory.time_calculated(params[:search_term])
      else
        SignupHistory.all 
      end
end

# in your model
def self.time_calculated(number)
  where('created_at > ?', number.to_i.hours.ago)
end
```

Comment: _its not working_ is not an unfull error description. What happens? is there an error? What is the message? How do the params and the database query in your log file look like?

Comment: No error whatsoever. but here is the log 
`Processing by Admin::Statistic::TrafficsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_term"=>"9", "commit"=>"Search"}
`
>SELECT `signup_histories`.* FROM `signup_histories` WHERE (created_at > '2018-09-13 07:40:27')`

Comment: What am supposed to see if I search 1 for an example is records filter of `Time.now - 1.hour` which means record created 1 hour ago

Comment: I updated my answer. I had `days.ago` instead of `hours.ago`

Comment: I noticed something. After I added `Time.now - number.to_i.hour` to your suggested solution, it works but I noticed something. I created a record 3 hours ago, so when I search 1 up to 3, it works. but when I searched 4 above it shows all record in the database

Comment: That is interesting because of `Time.now` and `Time.current` (which is used by `x.hours.ago`) are different. `Time.current` takes timezones into consideration whereas `Time.now` doesn't care about timezones. Therefore `Time.current` is preferred. I guess your applications timezone settings (in the app but in your database) are not consistent. In what time zone is your computer running, what timezone is your Rails app configured to use and what timezone does your created_at database column use?

Comment: Never mind. Solved. Am the one giving myself headache. When I search 5 hours, the record I created 3 hours ago definitely is supposed to be populated